# Implementing simple atom model using density functional theory (DFT)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, computational-physics, software, density-functional-theory

I am trying to write computer code which will find the energy and [density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory) for an atom with $Z$ protons and $N$ electrons. I am working in 1D for simplicity and would like to make the overall code as simple as possible (I am using Hartree units aswell). I am using also using the Hartree approximation. This is my overall algorithm:

1. Finds hydrogen like wave-functions (i.e. no electron-election interaction)
2. Works out density function via
   $n(z) = \sum_i \left | \phi_i(z)  \right |^2$
3. Works out Hartree potential
   $ V_H(r) = \int_0^\infty \frac{n(\vec{s})}{\left | \vec{r}-\vec{s} \right |} d\vec{s} $
4. Uses Kohn-Sham equation to find new individual wavefuncitons
   $\left (-\tfrac{1}{2}\bigtriangledown^2 + \frac{Z}{\left |r  \right |} + V_H(\vec{r}) + V_{EX}(\vec{r})  \right )\phi_i = \varepsilon_i \phi_i$
5. Go back to step 1. and repeat.

I am having a number of difficulty and would be very grateful for some help with any of my questions.

Firstly to compute the Hartree potential I need to turn it into a 1D problem, so we assume even spherical distribution of charge:

$ V_H(r) = \int_0^\infty 4\pi s^2 \frac{ n(s)}{\left |r-s\right |} ds $

However this blows up when $r = s$. I have been looking into Gauss's law but had no luck.

Additionally, I am unsure how to compute the exchange-correlation term. I am trying to find a function which I can easily implement.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Coss-posted to [Scientific Computation](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1648/183). Please don't do that, [it is strongly discouraged](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/896/520). You should take you best guess at the best fit and only try another site if you don't get satisfactory results from the first instance.

Comment: About your last question regarding the Hartee potential, please refer to this post:
[Hartree_potential_spherical](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377434/hartree-potential-coulomb-in-spherical-symmetry-expansion-of-spherical-harmon)

Answer (score 6):

The Hartree potential is typically calculated not through the integral you're giving, but by solving Poisson's equation. Look [here](http://inac.cea.fr/L_Sim/BigDFT/tutorials/talks/day-3-LG.pdf) or [there](http://theoretical-physics.net/dev/src/quantum/hf.html) for details about this calculation applied to DFT, and [here](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~jet/Teach/2004_3spr_IBMR/poisson.pdf) for what I found to be a good lower-level introduction to Poisson solvers in general. Good luck for your quest, it's really a nontrivial thing to do!

---

As an aside: what basis set are you going to employ?